# Javascript/Jquery to change class onclick?

Tags: javascript

I want to change a class onclick. What I have at the moment:

```
<script>
function changeclass() {

var NAME = document.getElementById("myclass")

NAME.className="mynewclass"

} 
</script>
```

But, ofcourse, its not working. Also, it should revert to previuos state onclick again.

My html:

```
<div id="showhide" class="meta-info" onclick="changeclass();">
```

So, whenever I press on #showhide myclass should change to mynewclass. Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: You use `getElementById`. This function takes the **id** an element, not its class.

Comment: `getElementById` namely *`"myclass"`* but anyways, in the HTML you use he ID `showhide`. Why?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

With jquery you could do to sth. like this, which will simply switch classes.

```
$('.showhide').click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('myclass');
    $(this).addClass('showhidenew');
});
```

If you want to switch classes back and forth on each click, you can use toggleClass, like so:

```
$('.showhide').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('myclass');
    $(this).toggleClass('showhidenew');
});
```

Comment: How this script should look if my showhide is not an id, its <div class = "showhide"> and my new class would be showhidenew  ?

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of difference. Changing from id(#) to class(.)changes your selector from #showhide to .showhide. The renaming of the new Class can simply be copied to the addClass / toggleClass, if you use the latter. See my edit.

Comment: Do I have to add something like onclick()? Or it should work like this whenever I press on clas .showhide?

Comment: I know that your variant is correct, but in my case it just doesnt work somehow.

Comment: Can you post your code somewhere (e.g. on http://jsfiddle.net/) or post a link to your actual page? Then I can help you more precisely.

Comment: I added this to the head <script>
$(".author").toggle(function(){
    $(this).attr("class", "authornew");
},function(){
    $(this).attr("class", "author");
});
</script>   You can check in here: http://techgeek.lt/?p=283  whenever a user press on the author name (blueish rectangular) the class should change form .author to .authorsomething. I want to change the color of the rectangular and add an arrow, but firstly ofcourse I want the class changing thing working. SunnyRed, Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: Try the following: Put your function inside a $(document).ready(function() { ... } block and use $("#showhide").click(function(){ toggleClass('meta-infonew'); });

Answer (score 8):

Your `getElementById` is looking for an element with id "myclass", but in your html the id of the DIV is `showhide`. Change to:

```
<script>
function changeclass() {

var NAME = document.getElementById("showhide")

NAME.className="mynewclass"

} 
</script>
```

Unless you are trying to target a different element with the id "myclass", then you need to make sure such an element exists.

Answer (score 7):

For a super succinct with jQuery approach try:

```
<div onclick="$(this).toggleClass('newclass')">click me</div>
```

Or pure JS:

```
<div onclick="this.classList.toggle('newclass');">click me</div>
```

Comment: I liked the idea of this approach INLINE.
But this specific syntax does not work, how can you have double quotes like that $(this) errors. etc etc
Can you provide an edit here with a working example

Comment: Good spot, fixed using single quotes

Comment: Yes, but it still does not work, I am no JS expert, still learning, but this simple example as much as it seems like a great idea it does not work for me.
I get "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick"
Please see for yourself... you can inspect for the console error.
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G9JA8STH3SSP

Comment: every other solutioin I can find suggests a function script, but I want an inline solution, as you say it would be more succinct. Sorry to be a pain.

Comment: If $ is not defined sounds like you've not added jQuery to the page.

Comment: I've added an alternate solution that doesn't require jQuery

Comment: Awesome Thank you, fyi it does not work for multiple classes, or at least I could not, I think because classList.toggle will return true if the class was added and false if it was removed, hence multiple is not boolean.
To do multiple I used classList.remove() and classList.add(), which allowed for comma separated strings, as per the below answer. +1:)

Comment: Good addition of the vanilla js answer, far more succinct, and does not require dependancies.

Answer (score 2):

Just using this will add "mynewclass" to the element with the id myElement and revert it on the next call.

```
<div id="showhide" class="meta-info" onclick="changeclass(this);">

function changeclass(element) {
    $(element).toggleClass('mynewclass');
}
```

Or for a slighly more jQuery way (you would run this after the DOM is loaded)

```
<div id="showhide" class="meta-info">

$('#showhide').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('mynewclass');
});
```

See a working example of this here: http://jsfiddle.net/S76WN/

Comment: Chad, how this script should look if my showhide is not an id, its <div class = "showhide"> and my new class would be showhidenew ?

Comment: You would change the jQuery selector `$('#showhide')` to something correct like `$('.showhide')` and the class in toggleClass to showhidenew.

Answer (score 2):

```
      <div class="liveChatContainer online">
        <div class="actions" id="change">
         <span class="item title">Need help?</span>
              <a href="/test" onclick="demo()"><i class="fa fa-smile-o"></i>Chat</a>
              <a href="/test"><i class="fa fa-smile-o"></i>Call</a>
              <a href="/test"><i class="fa fa-smile-o"></i>Email</a>
        </div>
              <a href="#" class="liveChatLabel">Contact</a>
     </div>
             <style>
               .actions_one{
               background-color: red;
                      } 
              </style>



           <script>
          function demo(){
      document.getElementById("change").setAttribute("class","actions_one");}
            </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would think this: http://jsfiddle.net/Skooljester/S3y5p/1/ should do it. If I don't have the class names 100% correct you can just change them to whatever you need them to be.

Comment: How this script should look if my showhide is not an id, its <div class = "showhide"> and my new class would be showhidenew ?

Answer (score 1):

Another example is:

```
$(".myClass").on("click", function () {
   var $this = $(this);

   if ($this.hasClass("show") {
    $this.removeClass("show");
   } else {
    $this.addClass("show");
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean that you want want an onclick event that changes a class.

Here is the answer if someone visits this question and is literally looking to assign a class and it's onclick with JQUERY.

It is somewhat counter-intuitive, but if you want to change the onclick event by changing the class you need to declare the onclick event to apply to elements of a parent object.

**HTML**

```
<div id="containerid">
     Text <a class="myClass" href="#" />info</a>
     Other Text <div class="myClass">other info</div>
</div>
<div id="showhide" class="meta-info">hide info</div>
```

**Document Ready**

```
$(function() {
     $("#containerid").on("click",".myclass",function(e){ /*do stuff*/ }
     $("#containerid").on("click",".mynewclass",function(e){ /*do different stuff*/ }
     $("#showhide").click(function() {changeclass()}
});
```

**Slight Tweak to Your Javascript**

```
<script>
function changeclass() {
        $(".myClass,.myNewClass").toggleClass('myNewClass').toggleClass('myClass');
} 
</script>
```

If you can't reliably identify a parent object you can do something like this.

```
$(function() {
     $(document).on("click",".myclass",function(e){}
     $(document).on("click",".mynewclass",function(e){}
});
```

If you just want to hide the items you might find it simpler to use .hide() and .show().