# Edit div class name on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So basically I have a bunch of nav buttons that I want to change the name of when the user clicks the button.

The original div class name is something like "home", and when the user clicks on it I want it to be "home_active" so that the CSS attributes will change the background-image.

```js
$('.click').click(function() {
  var clicked_url = $(this).attr('class');
  var updated_url = clicked_url + "_active";
  $(this).attr('class') = updated_url;
});
```

```css
.item_active {
  background-color: teal;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="item">item 1</a>
<a href="#" class="item">item 2</a>
<a href="#" class="item">item 3</a>
```

Comment: will recommend you to use toggleClass() from jQuery and write your CSS code to match class and active

.className.active{
//css code here
}

Comment: Refer this => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014385/javascript-jquery-to-change-class-onclick

Answer (score 2):

You shall use the `.addClass()` method add a class to the element:

```
$('.click').click(function() {
    var clicked_url = $(this).attr('class');
    var updated_url = clicked_url + "_active";
    $(this).removeClass(clicked_url); // remove the old class
    $(this).addClass(updated_url); // add the new class
});
```

However, as a good practice, it is better to add a modifier class, such as "active" to the existing class, preserving the original class name.

Then use the following CSS:

```css
.click.active {
    background: red;
}
```

The JS code would look like this:

```
$('.click').click(function() {
    $('.click.active').removeClass('active'); // remove active class from all other nav items
    $(this).addClass('active'); // add active to the nav item the users just clicked on
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Jquery functions:

```
$(this).hasClass("className");
$(this).addClass("className");
$(this).removeClass("className");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.click').click(function() {
var clicked_url = $(this).attr('class');
var updated_url = clicked_url + "_active";
$(this).removeClass(updated_url)
$(this).addClass(updated_url)});
```

Answer (score 1):

Almost there - but remember to use `attr` to reset the class value. And you most likely want to *remove* `_active` from the other `.click` elements, so this is the only one.

```
$(".click").click(function() {
  $(".click").each(function() {
    $(this).attr("class", $(this).attr("class").replace(/_active/, ""));
  });
  $(this).attr("class", $(this).attr("class") + "_active");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where class `.click` is but there is `.item` and `.click(...)` method is ok -- I prefer to use `.on('click', ...)` (see the difference between [**.click()**](https://api.jquery.com/click/) and [**.on()**](https://api.jquery.com/on/)).

```
$('.item').on('click', function() {...
```

Since objective is to simply change the style of a clicked link by changing its class then it's better to assign a common class (which was done: `.item`) and a class that sets the state (a separate class: `.active`).

```
$(this).toggleClass('active');
```

If you wish to apply this to additional tags, simply modify the outer selector

```
$('.item, :button').on('click', function() {...
```

The selector above will listen for clicks on anything with the class `.item` *and* any `<button>` and `<input type='button'>` tags.

---

It wasn't very clear what the desired behavior was so there's two demos:

> **Demo 1:** Click any link to add/remove `.active` class

or

> **Demo 2:** Click any link to add/remove `.active` class ***exclusively***

#### Demo 1

**Click any link to add/remove `.active` class**

```js
$('.item').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: teal;
  color: white
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="item">item 1</a>
<a href="#" class="item">item 2</a>
<a href="#" class="item">item 3</a>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

#### Demo 2

**Click any link to add/remove `.active` class *exclusively***

```js
$('.item').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  $('.item').not(this).removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: teal;
  color: white
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="item">item 1</a>
<a href="#" class="item">item 2</a>
<a href="#" class="item">item 3</a>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple things. First, you want to select elements with a class name of "item," not "click." Secondly, you were using the `attr()` function wrong. Instead of `attr('class') = var`, you want to set the var as the second parameter, e.g. `attr('class', var)`.

Edit: Finally, you should check in your click event whether or not the link has been previously clicked (i.e. whether it already has the "_active" suffix):

```js
$('.item').click(function() {
    var clicked_url = $(this).attr('class');
    var updated_url;
    if(clicked_url.includes("_active")){
        updated_url = "item";
    }else{
       updated_url = "item_active";
    }
    $(this).attr('class', updated_url);
});
```

```css
.item_active {
  background-color: teal;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="item">item 1</a>
<a href="#" class="item">item 2</a>
<a href="#" class="item">item 3</a>
```