# Jquery find() to get Icon <i> Class

Tags: jquery

I am very new to jquery and haven't been able to find a solution for my problem. I have a table created for some messages. At the beginning of a messages row there is a `fontawesome` icon showing the message is not expanded. Once clicked and expanded I want that icon to change to a different one. I have been toying with a function found elsewhere on this site which uses the value of the first `<td>` in a row to show either `+` or `-`.

Here's the function followed by my table:

```
$(function() {
    $("td[colspan=7]").find("p").hide();
    $("table").click(function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        var $target = $(event.target);
        if ( $target.closest("td").attr("colspan") > 1 ) {
            $target.closest("td").children("p").slideUp();

            $target.closest("tr").prev().find("td:first").html("+");//NOT MINE - CHANGE

        } else {
            $target.closest("tr").next().find("p").slideToggle();

            if ($target.closest("tr").find("td:first").html() == "+")//NOT MINE - CHANGE
                $target.closest("tr").find("td:first").html("-");//NOT MINE - CHANGE
            else
                $target.closest("tr").find("td:first").html("+"); //NOT MINE - CHANGE

        }                    
    });
});
```

...

```
                    echo "<tr class='message-body'>";
                    echo "<th><i class='far fa-envelope'></i> ".$title."</th>";
                    echo "<th></th>";
                    echo "<th>".$date."</th>";
                    echo "<th></th>";
                    echo "<th></th>";
                    echo "<th></th>";
                    echo '<th><div class="right"><form method="post" action="">
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$id.'">
                        <button class="rem-button"> Delete</button></form></div></th>';
                    echo "</tr>";
                    echo "<tr colspan='7'><td class='message-body-body' colspan='7'><p><br>".$body."</p></td></tr>";
```

Ideally I want to do something like:

closed -> first `<i>` class is =  far fa-envelope

opened -> first `<i>` class is =  far fa-envelope-open

**EDIT**

Currently the function allows me to click a row and expand to show the body of a message. Before expanding i want to keep the `envelope` icon. After expanding I want that icon to change to `envelope-open`.

**EDIT 2**

I need this line

```
$target.closest("tr").prev().find("td:first").html("+");
```

changed to this one (but functional)

```
$target.closest("tr").prev().find("i:first").class.html("far fa-envelope");
```

the other lines needing to be changed will be, in a similar manner

**EDIT 3**
[solution my question is based off of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897396/can-a-table-row-expand-and-close)

**EDIT 4**
[My Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zqvL8u91/2/) not sure how to link fontawesome here

Comment: I don't clearly understand what you want, you want that when icon is clicked, then change the class of the `<i>` tag?

Comment: @CalvinNunes I added an edit. Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript/Jquery to change class onclick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014385/javascript-jquery-to-change-class-onclick)

Comment: It looks like you are asking to handle a case of clicking on the `i` or message, yet your event binding is for clicking on the `table`.

Comment: @Taplar I want the clicking on the table. I just want the icon (only for that row) to change when the row is clicked to expand the message.

Comment: @Taplar added second edit

Comment: @CalvinNunes added second edit

Comment: @FamousAv8er, can you provide a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) to better illustrate what you have?

Comment: @mgarcia see edit 4

Comment: @WOUNDEDSTevenJones not exactly sure how to use those in conditional statements   `if ($target.closest("tr").find("td:first").html() == "+")`

Comment: The `<i>` element is not in a `<td>` in your code, it's in a `<th>`. After reading one of the answers in the question you referenced, I can see why the click event is on the table.

Comment: There is a problem with your design. If you add the envelope icon to a `<th>`, that icon will apply to ***all*** messages. You need the icon in a `<td>` so you'll have one for each message and you can control them individually. Same issue with your delete button. `<th>` is for the *headings*.

Comment: @EternalHour I agree my design could use some work, however the expanding and deletion currently work flawlessly on the row selected. Im hoping that in the same function that expands my selected row, I can change just that rows icon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, in my opinion `<th>` should be reserved for the column headings. Then you can put your message content in `<td>` tags. Also, by hiding the `<p>` tag by default, no need to hide it.

In order to switch the classes, you can use `toggleClass()` method. Here is an example I put together with my suggestions to what you've provided. You can further optimize it by adding classes to each `<td>` which would allow you to remove `first()` and target the elements individually.

```js
$(function() {
  $("table").click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    var $target = $(event.target.parentNode);
 
    $target.children().first().find('i')
    .toggleClass("fa-envelope fa-envelope-open");
    
    $target.next().find(".message-body-body").slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
th {
background-color: #ccc;
}
.message-row {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.message-body-body {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  /* prevents element from flashes when page is loaded */
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class='message-body'>
    <th></th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>To</th>
    <th>From</th>
    <th>Action</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="message-row">
    <td><i class='far fa-envelope message-icon'></i></td>
    <td>09/26/2019</td>
    <td>Message #1</td>
    <td>someone@demo.com</td>
    <td>someone@demo.com</td>
    <td>
      <div class="right">
        <form method="post" action="">
          <input type="hidden" name="id" value="20">
          <button class="rem-button"> Delete</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr colspan='6'>
    <td class='message-body-body' colspan='6'>
      This is the message body #1
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="message-row">
    <td><i class='far fa-envelope message-icon'></i></td>
    <td>09/26/2019</td>
    <td>Message #2</td>
    <td>someone@demo.com</td>
    <td>someone@demo.com</td>
    <td>
      <div class="right">
        <form method="post" action="">
          <input type="hidden" name="id" value="20">
          <button class="rem-button"> Delete</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr colspan='6'>
    <td class='message-body-body' colspan='6'>
      This is the message body #2
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Im not able to play with this at the moment but I will later. I appreciate the extra effort you are putting in to help me. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$target.closest("tr").prev().find("i:first").toggleClass("fa-envelope fa-envelope-open");
```

Another possible solution:

```
$('#message-table').find('th:first-child i').toggleClass("fa-envelope fa-envelope-open");
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gbhsa19v/

Comment: @FamousAv8er it will work correct. See this fiddle I've made: https://jsfiddle.net/gbhsa19v/

Comment: so this does work and I appreciate your solution however, when applied to my code this will change the icon for each row in the table rather than just the row we are clicking

Comment: @FamousAv8er you just want to it to slide up/down and change the icon when clicked on <th> ? When clicking in any table row, the table should be hidden or still be visible?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/obyv8e4L/  I think my change here shows what youre asking. The rows below our expanded row just slide down