# How to change a chevron from pointing right to pointing down when you click on it in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

[image]

I am getting the chevron-down icon from https://fontawesome.com/icons/chevron-down and the chevron-right icon from https://fontawesome.com/icons/chevron-right . I am unsure of where to start to make it so that when you click on the SHOW LESS text, it will change into SHOW MORE and the chevron will change into a chevron-right.

Also, how do you make it so that the content also appears below SHOW LESS when you have clicked on it?

Comment: Capture the click event and toggle the class.  You did not share any code so it will be hard to answer.

Comment: You are looking for the `details` element which is the semantically correct element here: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript/Jquery to change class onclick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014385/javascript-jquery-to-change-class-onclick)

Answer (score 4):

Use the HTML5 `details` element, which

1. is the semantically correct element here,
2. does not require any Javascript,
3. is compatible with screen readers as part of the HTML standard,
4. does not even require font awesome because it already comes with a chevron that does exactly what you're asking for.

```css
.restyled summary { text-transform: uppercase; }
.restyled summary::marker { content: "› "; }

.restyled summary::-webkit-details-marker { content: "› "; }
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>Show more</summary>
  <p>More info about the details.</p>
</details>

<details class="restyled">
  <summary>Show more</summary>
  <p>More info about the details.</p>
</details>
```

> https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details

Comment: Chrome latest here, no visual difference between normal and restyled.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the solution! However, I am currently trying to learn Javascript and wanted to find a way to make it so that I can toggle a "Show More" or "Show Less" button through Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

A quick possible start.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".arrow").forEach(function(e){
  e.addEventListener("pointerdown",function(){
    toggleArrow(e.id)
  }  
  ,false)
})

function toggleArrow(e){
  if (document.getElementById(e).className === "arrow show"){
    document.getElementById(e).className = "arrow hide"
  } else {
    document.getElementById(e).className = "arrow show"
  }
}
```

```css
.arrow{
  font-size: 2rem;
  cursor: pointer
}

.show::before{
  content: "⇩"
}

.hide::before{
  content: "⇨"
}
```

```html
<div id="arrow1" class="arrow hide">MORE</div>
<div id="arrow2" class="arrow hide">MORE</div>
<div id="arrow3" class="arrow hide">MORE</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution.
run this.

```js
function toggle(){

    var chevElement =  document.getElementById('chevron');
    var button = document.getElementById('toggle-button');

    if( chevElement.className.includes('right')){
          button.innerHTML = 'Show Less &nbsp &nbsp <i id="chevron" class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>';
    }
    else if(chevElement.className.includes('down')){
          button.innerHTML = 'Show More  &nbsp <i id="chevron" class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>';
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Simple Collapsible</h2>
  <p>Click on the button to toggle between showing and hiding content.</p>
  <button id='toggle-button'type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo" onclick="toggle()">Show More &nbsp <i id="chevron" class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></button>
  
  <div id="demo" class="collapse">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I was able to get the button to switch from chevrons and change text, however, the text below does not show up. How does your text show up when you click the button?

Comment: @waldo233 It is done by Collapse js plugin from Bootstrap. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/collapse/

Comment: You can use a link with the href attribute, or a button with the data-target attribute. In both cases, the data-toggle="collapse" is required. And the element that contains the collapsing text must have class="collapse" . Remember to add the CDN links that I have added in the header.