# How to toggle between classes using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a rating star in my page, and I'm trying to toggle back and forth between "fa fa-star" class and "fa fa-star checked" class I have read about this here: [Javascript/Jquery to change class onclick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014385/javascript-jquery-to-change-class-onclick)
And this is my implementation (it didn't work)

```js
$('.fa fa-star').click(function() { $(this).toggleClass('fa fa-star'); $(this).toggleClass('fa fa-star checked'); });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <span onclick="rating" class="fa fa-star"></span>
    <span onclick="rating" class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
    <span onclick="rating" class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
    <span onclick="rating" class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
    <span onclick="rating" class="fa fa-star"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Try `$(this).toggleClass('fa-star fa-checked');` -- the `checked` class is not a FontAwesome icon class.

Comment: You could use an if statement to see if the class exists and if it does then toggle the other class you want.

Comment: I supplemented my answer with a solution with the same behavior as that of prettyInPink (minimum 1 star)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to toggle the `checked` class for a simplified rating.

```js
$('.stars i').click(function() {

  $('.stars i.checked').removeClass('checked');
  for (let i = 0; i < $(this).index() + 2; i++) {

      $('.stars i:nth-of-type(' + i + ')').addClass('checked');

  }

});
```

```css
.stars i {
  color: #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.stars i.checked {
  color: #dfd022;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-KfkfwYDsLkIlwQp6LFnl8zNdLGxu9YAA1QvwINks4PhcElQSvqcyVLLD9aMhXd13uQjoXtEKNosOWaZqXgel0g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<div class="stars">
  <i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i>
</div>
```

If you need the option of being able to convert stars back to '0', you can use the following option:

```js
$('.stars i').click(function() {
  
  if($(this).index() === 0 && $('.stars i.checked').length === 1){
    $('.stars i.checked').removeClass('checked');
  } else {
    $('.stars i.checked').removeClass('checked');
    for (let i = 0; i < $(this).index() + 2; i++) {
        $('.stars i:nth-of-type(' + i + ')').addClass('checked');
    }
  }

});
```

```css
.stars i {
  color: #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.stars i.checked {
  color: #dfd022;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-KfkfwYDsLkIlwQp6LFnl8zNdLGxu9YAA1QvwINks4PhcElQSvqcyVLLD9aMhXd13uQjoXtEKNosOWaZqXgel0g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<div class="stars">
  <i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Works, but I think OP will need to rethink this design.  Star ratings usually highlight all the stars below rather than single stars.  +1

Comment: @Roberto, def agreed, updated it with somewhat better approach.

Comment: your code does not work: there is no way to return to zero stars as soon as one or more has been selected

Comment: @MisterJojo, I agree there could be improvements (depending on needs), but it does work, many rating systems only allow a minimum of 1 star. Having said that, your code acts weird as well, if you select an amount of stars less than a previously specified amount, it does not show the correct amount, but one less, because of toggling the class. Peace amigo!

Comment: this toggle is in the tittle requirement...

Comment: @MisterJojo, why do you want to include an example of my code if it isn't working? Je suis confused...

Answer (score 0):

maybe that...

```js
document.querySelectorAll('i.fa-star')
.forEach( (star,indx,arr) =>
  {
  star.onclick =_=> 
    {
    let chk = star.classList.toggle('checked')
    arr.forEach((s,i) =>
      s.classList.toggle('checked', i<indx ? true: i===indx ? chk : false))
    }
  })
```

```css
body {
  background : darkslategrey;
  font-size  : 24px;
  }
i.fa-solid.fa-star {
  color  : lightgray;
  cursor : pointer;
  }
i.fa-solid.fa-star.checked {
  color  : gold;
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" />

<div>
  <i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i>
</div>
```

## If you want the same as prettyInPink's answer :

```js
document.querySelectorAll('i.fa-star')
.forEach( (star,indx,arr) => star.onclick =_=> 
  arr.forEach((s,i) => s.classList.toggle('checked', i<=indx )))
```

```css
body {
  background : darkslategrey;
  font-size  : 24px;
  }
i.fa-solid.fa-star {
  color  : lightgray;
  cursor : pointer;
  }
i.fa-solid.fa-star.checked {
  color  : gold;
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" />

<div>
  <i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i>
</div>
```